# Find all the combinations that return a particular value from a function

Tags: algorithm

This is a variation on finding all the combinations that add to a target, with two constraints:

- We have a limited set of numbers to work with.
- The numbers must result in the target number when fed into a separate function.

In this case, the limited set of numbers include 25, 50, 100, 200, 450, 700, 1100, 1800, 2300, 2900, 3900, 5000, 5900, 7200, 8400, etc.

And the function is to add the values together and then multiply by a number based on how many numbers we had:

- If 1 number, multiply by 1.
- If 2 numbers, multiply by 1.5
- If 3-6 numbers, multiply by 2
- If 7-10 numbers, multiply by 2.5
- If >10 numbers, multiply by 3

Examples:

[50, 50, 50] => 300

[100, 100] => 300

Target numbers include 300, 600, 900, 1500, 3000, 3600, 4400, 5600, 6400, 7600, 9600, etc.

My intuition is that this can't be done recursively, because each step doesn't know the multiplier that will eventually be applied.

Comment: my approach would be a dynamic programming solution where DP[X][Y] = whether we can make a sum of Y using X numbers.  For example, DP[75][2] would be True, since we can sum to 75 by adding 50 and 25.  From this "raw sum" you can calculate the adjusted sum, by multiplying by the multiplier (adjusted sum being 75 * 1.5).  The DP recursion would be DP[X][Y] = Ǝ(DP[X-n][Y-1] for all n in the limited set of numbers).  Haven't thought it through entirely, there might be an additional complication, but that's how I would start approaching the problem.

Comment: I guess it depends upon the range of the numbers. If Sum(Numbers) * Count(Numbers) can be stored in memory then the Memoization approach would be feasible.

Comment: A solution like the Coin Change problem but with scaling the sum everytime the count enters a new range would be possible?

Comment: There are 28 numbers, and 19 targets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a recursive example in JavaScript that seems to answer the requirements:

```js
function getNextM(m, n){
  if (n == 1)
    return 1.5;
  if (n == 2)
    return 2;
  if (n == 6)
    return 2.5;
  if (n == 10)
    return 3;

  return m;
}

function g(A, t, i, sum, m, comb){
  if (sum * m == t)
    return [comb];
    
  if (sum * m > t || i == A.length)
    return [];
    
  let n = comb.length;
    
  let result = g(A, t, i + 1, sum, m, comb);
  
  const max = Math.ceil((t - sum) / A[i]);

  let _comb = comb;
  
  for (let j=1; j<=max; j++){
    _comb = _comb.slice().concat(A[i]);
    sum = sum + A[i];
    m = getNextM(m, n);
    n = n + 1;
    result = result.concat(g(
      A, t, i + 1, sum, m, _comb)); 
  }
  
  return result;
}

function f(A, t){
  return g(A, t, 0, 0, 1, []);
}


var A = [25, 50, 100, 200, 450, 700, 1100, 1800, 2300, 2900, 3900, 5000, 5900, 7200, 8400];

var t = 300;

console.log(JSON.stringify(f(A, t)));
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a small script in Python3 that may solve this problem.

```
multiply_factor = [0,1,1.5,2,2,2,2,2.5,2.5,2.5,2.5,3]
def get_multiply_factor(x):
    if x< len(multiply_factor):
        return multiply_factor[x]
    else:
        return multiply_factor[-1]


numbers = [25, 50, 100, 200, 450, 700, 1100, 1800, 2300, 2900, 3900, 5000, 5900, 7200, 8400]
count_of_numbers = len(numbers)


# dp[Count_of_Numbers]
dp = [[] for j in range(count_of_numbers+1)]

#Stores multiplying_factor * sum of numbers for each unique Count, See further
sum_found =[set() for j in range(count_of_numbers+1)]

# Stores Results in Unordered_Map for answering Queries
master_record={}

#Initializing Memoization Array
for num in numbers:
    dp[1].append(([num],num*get_multiply_factor(1)))

for count in range(2,count_of_numbers+1):   # Count of Numbers
    for num in numbers:
        for previous_val in dp[count-1]:
            old_factor = get_multiply_factor(count-1)   #Old Factor for Count Of Numbers = count-1
            new_factor = get_multiply_factor(count)     #New Factor for Count Of Numbers = count

            # Multiplying Factor does not change
            if old_factor==new_factor:
                # Scale Current Number and add
                new_sum = num*new_factor+previous_val[1]
            else:
                #Otherwise, We rescale the entire sum
                new_sum = (num+previous_val[1]//old_factor)*new_factor

            # Check if NEW SUM has already been found for this Count of Numbers
            if new_sum not in sum_found[count]:
                # Add to current Count Array
                dp[count].append(([num]+previous_val[0],new_sum))
                # Mark New Sum as Found for Count Of Numbers = count
                sum_found[count].add(new_sum)
                if new_sum not in master_record:
                    # Store Seected Numbers in Master Record for Answering Queries
                    master_record[new_sum] = dp[count][-1][0]



# for i in dp:
#   print(i)
print(master_record[1300])
print(master_record[300])
print(master_record[2300])
print(master_record[7950])
print(master_record[350700.0])
```

Output :-

```
[100, 100, 450]
[100, 100]
[25, 25, 1100]
[25, 50, 3900]
[1800, 5900, 8400, 8400, 8400, 8400, 8400, 8400, 8400, 8400, 8400, 8400, 8400, 8400, 8400]
[Finished in 0.3s]
```

My Algo in a nutshell.

```
Iterate over Count[2, Limit], I've considered limit = Number of Elements
    Iterate over List of Numbers
        Iterate over Sums found for previous count.
            Calculate New Sum,
            If it does not exist for current count, update.
```

I am assuming that the number of queries will be large so that memorization pays off. The upper limit for count may break my code as the possibilities may grow exponentially.

Comment: The results for master_record[300] should be `[[100, 100], [25, 25, 100], [50, 50, 50], [25, 25, 50, 50], [25, 25, 25, 25, 50], [25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25]]`

Can you clarify whether this algorithm can do this?

Comment: No, it can't sorry. You're looking for all possible ways to find the required sum?

Comment: Yes. One thought for optimizing is to truncate the list of numbers to only those below the target. We can also try the smallest number first, just to get the max array size, even if the rest of the algorithm starts with the highest.